# if $A \times B$ is infinite prove either $A$ or $B$ is infinite.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

if sets $A$ and $B$ are such that $A \times B$ is infinite, prove either $A$ or $B$ is infinite.

proof: let $f: A \times B \to A \times B$ be an injection (but not onto). suppose $B$ is finite. I want to show that $A$ must be infinite. so I need to find an injection that maps $A$ to $A$ which is not onto. I need a hint to approach this, please. any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If both $A$ and $B$ are finite then $A \times B$ is finite as well.

Comment: The question is a bit more subtle if you use Dedekind-infiniteness (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set) and don't assume the axiom of choice. Is that your setting? I got the impression because of your proof attempt.